# Looping through a set of builds in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

My TeamCity project has builds created in below fashion:

1. Build-1
2. Build-2
3. Build-3
4. Build-4
5. Build-5
6. Build-6
7. Build-7

I have currently chained the execution of all the builds one-by-one serially in this project by setting the "Finish Build Trigger" in each of the builds from #2 through #7.

What I'd like to achieve is, loop through builds #3 to #6 with the loop parameter being files from a certain directory (one file at a time in the loop) from the VCS Root attached to build #3. Is this feasible? If yes, I would like know, how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for such a dynamic scenario you need to use [TeamCity REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/REST+API).

I'd wrap builds #3 to #6 to separate build config called let's say `Loop3To6`.

`Loop3To6` config has a build step which has a script which loops through files from certain directory and for each file you trigger builds #3, #4, #5, #6 using [Trigger Build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild)

Then `Loop3To6` set Finish Build Trigger to Build #2 and Build #7 set Finish Build Trigger to `Loop3To6`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that triggering the builds #3. #4, #5, #6 with the TeamCity REST API calls would be an asynchronous process, meaning, I do not have any way to ensure that build #4 is not started until #3 is finished, #5 is not started #4 is finished and so on, which is the requirement.

Comment: You're right it will be async but you can check whether #3 is done before starting #4 using another API call (simply HTTP GET query) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildLocator

Comment: It might be a little effort to implement but will pay off later once you're sure your build architecture won't change drastically in a week or so :)